# How to attach a p7s signature received from an API to a PDF, preferably in JAVA

Tags: java, itext, pdfbox, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I need to follow the following steps:

1. Prepare the signature document
2. Calculate which bytes (bytes-ranges) of the file prepared in step 1 should enter the hash computation. Unlike a detached signature, the hash calculation for PDF enveloped signatures is not the SHA256 hash of the original (full) document. It is a part of the document prepared in step 1.
3. Compute the SHA256 hash of these bytes
4. Submit the SHA256 hash to the signPKCS7 operation of this API.
5. The result of the signPKCS7 operation must be encoded in hexadecimal and embedded in the space that was previously allocated in the document in step 1.

I get a .crt certificate and a .p7s file from the API. I've tried several ways to attach this p7s signature to the PDF

When checking the p7s file and the pdf prepared in step 1 on the platform made available by them, it is validated. But in my attempts to attach the p7s to the PDF it doesn't work.

```java
    private void signature() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        pdf = new File(pdfUploadedAddress);
        pdf.mkdirs();

        BouncyCastleProvider providerBC = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.addProvider(providerBC);

        CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", "BC");

        Certificate[] chain = new Certificate[1];
        File initialFile = new File(pathFileCertificate);
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);

        chain[0] = factory.generateCertificate(stream);

        emptySignature(pdfUploadedAddress, TEMP, "sig", chain);

        createSignature(TEMP, DEST + RESULT_FILES[0], "sig", chain);

    }

    public void emptySignature(String src, String dest, String fieldname, Certificate[] chain)
            throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest), new StampingProperties());
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setPageRect(new Rectangle(36, 748, 200, 100)).setPageNumber(1).setCertificate(chain[0]);
        signer.setFieldName(fieldname);

        /*
         * ExternalBlankSignatureContainer constructor will create the PdfDictionary for
         * the signature information and will insert the /Filter and /SubFilter values
         * into this dictionary. It will leave just a blank placeholder for the
         * signature that is to be inserted later.
         */
        IExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite,
                PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);

        // Sign the document using an external container.
        // 8192 is the size of the empty signature placeholder.
        signer.signExternalContainer(external, 8192);

    }

public void createSignature(String src, String dest, String fieldName, Certificate[] chain)
            throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

    
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest)) {
            PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, fos, new StampingProperties());
            IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(chain);

            signer.signDeferred(signer.getDocument(), fieldName, fos, external);

        }
    
    }
class MyExternalSignatureContainer implements IExternalSignatureContainer {

        protected Certificate[] chain;

        public MyExternalSignatureContainer(Certificate[] chain) {
            this.chain = chain;
        }

        public byte[] sign(InputStream is) throws GeneralSecurityException {

            try {

                File file = new File("src/main/resources/signature.p7s");
                byte[] p7sFile = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());

                PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain[0].getEncoded(), null);
                return sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(p7sFile, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null, null);

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
            }
        }

        public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
            signDic.put(PdfName.Filter, PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite);
            // change here
            signDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
        }
    }
```

The error returned when running this code was as follows:

com.itextpdf.kernel.exceptions.PdfException: Unknown PdfException.

In another attempt, replacing

PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain[0].getEncoded(), null);
return sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(p7sFile, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null, null);

per

return p7sFile;

The signed PDF was generated, but it generated an error in the API verifier.

Attributes -> Required Attributes -> IdMessageDigest -> Disapproved. Failed to construct the attribute. Problems getting the hash

IdContentType -> Approved

**To response Mkl's post:**

Signed PDF
https://www.dropbox.com/s/unwlfp4f4ipvijh/SignedPDF.pdf?dl=0

**Problem solved**

1. Replacing the lines, following mkl's tip in the comments

PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain[0].getEncoded(), null);
return sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(p7sFile, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null, null);

per

return p7sFile;

2. I was calculating and hashing the temporary PDF with the blank signature to the API, however it must be hashed without the signature part and iText already helps you with that. The sign() method receives an InputStream that must be used to hash the prepared PDF correctly.
   The sign method now looks like this:

````
public byte[] sign(InputStream is) throws GeneralSecurityException {

            try {
                BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
                byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(is, digest.getMessageDigest("SHA256"));

                //API call that generates the .p7s signature
                signPKCS7API(hash);

                File file = new File("src/main/resources/signature.p7s");
                byte[] p7sFile = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());

                return p7sFile;

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
            }
        } ```
````

Comment: `PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain[0].getEncoded(), null); return sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(p7sFile, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null, null);` - This makes no sense. If your signing service returns a CMS signature container, use that and don't try to reconstruct one.

Comment: *"replacing .. per .. The signed PDF was generated, but it generated an error in the API verifier."* - please share the PDF for analysis.

Comment: Thanks mkl, found out my mistake. Your contribution on "This makes no sense" helped too. But, another mistake made me lose a lot of time too. I will post the fix soon.

Comment: Ok. I now would have had some time for analysis. Great that you already found out yourself.